# Bootstrap Popover reconnect to new caller

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am creating Bootstrap Popovers for my bootstrap-table to provide the table with filtering functionality. My intention is to enable column-wise filtering and sorting for the table, mimicking the look and feel that Excel offers.

For this purpose, I am attaching a dynamic popover to each funnel icon in the table header. However, I've encountered an issue where the table's DOM is regenerated every time I apply a filter or sorting. This regeneration causes the currently open popover to lose its connection to the caller (the funnel icon). Is there a way to reestablish the popover's connection to the newly generated icon?

Currently, my workaround involves closing the popover and generating a new one whenever this regeneration happens. Unfortunately, this approach results in a slight flickering effect and causes the filters' scrollbar to lose its state.

I wonder if there is any other way to solve this problem...

```
$('th i.bi-funnel').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            const columnFieldName = $(this).closest('th').data('field');

            if($(this).attr('aria-describedby') === undefined) {
                $(this).popover({
                    content: createPopoverContent(columnFieldName),
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'click',
                    placement: 'right',
                    animation: false
                });
            }

            $(this).popover('toggle');
        });
    });
```

Currently, my workaround involves closing the popover and generating a new one whenever this regeneration happens. Unfortunately, this approach results in a slight flickering effect and causes the filters' scrollbar to lose its state.